# Get model by related table in Yii Active Record (Country > City > Village)?

Tags: activerecord, yii

For example i have a DB like this.
Country > City > Village

It explained this way>>

Village have `cityid` which is belong to `id` of `city`

city have `coutryid` which is belong `id` of `country`

How do i get a village by defining contry id in Yii Active Record ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. What is the relationship between city and village? Why do you expect "a" village given a specific country?

Comment: i have edited my question. Is it clear now? @Jon

Answer (score 1):

set up the "Relations" in the AR model and when you perform a find in the parent model the other models are lazy loaded by default, and you access the other joins by the parent. See 'Relational Active Record' in the docs for step by step instructions or see [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/26614-relational-active-record/page__p__128065__hl__relational+active+record#entry128065).

Answer (score 0):

you have to user the active record find or findBySql and use join for if these are three table.

http://www.tipstank.com/2010/08/22/yii-find-examples-a-basic-guide/

http://www.roseindia.net/sql/sqljoin/mysql-join-3-tables.shtml